# How to keep the header path if using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I don't know how to describe this question clearly,I can't speak English very well.

I'm creating a CocoaPods Spec, I got these folders and files in my project：

`MySDK/*.(h,m)
MySDK/AdvertisementSDKS/Millennial/*.(h,m)
MySDK/AdvertisementSDKS/Millennial/SDK/MillennialMedia.framework`

and Podspec's source_files looks like

`s.source_files = "*.{h,m}", "AdvertisementSDKS/**/*.{h,m}"`

also include framework

`s.vendored_frameworks = 'AdvertisementSDKS/Millennial/SDK/MillennialMedia.framework`

in Millennial folder there is a **.m** file that imports：

`#import <MillennialMedia/MMInterstitial.h>`

When I try compile, Error occurs, Because compiler cant find the path of  MillennialMedia/MMInterstitial.h
The correct import way is

`#import <MMInterstitial.h>`

Are there any settings I missed, that I can set to keep the original #include path?

Because there are lots of other same issue, I have to modify it one by one...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll answer my own question:
I missed some settings of Podspec, Just simply add

```
spec.header_dir = './'
```

(The directory path depends on your project)

To your podspec, Then, It'll keep the original path works

Don't need to modify the header path! Woohoo!